# Any way to get a creative ID from an ad ID, or vice-versa?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I don't see any way in the docs to get a creative ID from an ad ID, or the other way around.

You can get a list of creative IDs given a single image ID: `creatives` is a field in the [ad image endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image).

But there is no `ads` field in the [ad creative](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative) endpoint, and there is no `creatives` field in the [ad insights endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights).

Am I missing something?